# How to change action of Ship button to own Module/controller/action in Magento admin order view screen?

Tags: magento

[image: Magento admin]

How can I change the action of the `Ship` button in the `Order view` screen in the Magento backend? The image above depicts the `Ship`button I mean. I want to point it to my own controller/action of my own module. I want to do this as clean as possible, to keep Magento upgradeable without breaking my module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try create a custom module that rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View`

**config.xml:**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
 </global>
```

**Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php:**

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {
        public function getShipUrl()
        {
            //add your custom url
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/start');
        }
}
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php

Read more @ [How to add new button to order view in Magento admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642599/how-to-add-new-button-to-order-view-in-magento-admin-panel)

If you want to also change title update

```
    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('ship') && $order->canShip()
        && !$order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()) {
        $this->_addButton('order_ship', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
```